# JPA: Multiple tables are associated and conditional queries are used, but the condition does not work

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to implement the following SQL with jpa：

```
    select u.id,u.name,u.address,o.title,o.description from user u
    left join orderd o
    where o.title='order1';
```

But it didn't turn out the way I wanted.

I'm using springboot and spring data jpa.

```
    //User Entity
    @Entity
    public class User {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        Integer id;

        String username;

        String addr;

        @JoinColumn(name = "userid", referencedColumnName = "id")
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        Set<Orderd> orderds;
    }

    //Orderd entity
    @Entity
    public class Orderd {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        Integer id;

        String title;

        String description;
    }



    @Test
        public void findByUserIdAndOrderdTitle() {
            Specification<User> userSpecification = new Specification<User>() {

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public Predicate toPredicate(Root<User> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

                    Join<User, Orderd> orderdJoin = root.join("orderds", JoinType.LEFT);

                    Predicate userIdEqual = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("id"), 1);
                    Predicate orderdTitleEqual = criteriaBuilder.equal(orderdJoin.get("title"), "apple");

                    criteriaQuery.where(userIdEqual, orderdTitleEqual);

                    return criteriaQuery.getRestriction();
                }
            };
            List<User> all = userRepository.findAll(userSpecification);

            for (User user : all) {
                System.out.println(user.getOrderds());
            }
    }
```

I get the value:

```
    [Orderd {
        id = 2, title = 'apple', description = 'this is a apple'
    }, Orderd {
        id = 1, title = 'orange', description = 'this is a orange'
    }]
```

But,I hope this:

```
    [Orderd {
        id = 1, title = 'orange', description = 'this is a orange'
    }]
```

I think I used id filtering on the user table and title filtering on the order table, which is actually a record,but it is two.

Below is the SQL for log printing:

```
    Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.addr as addr2_1_, user0_.username as username3_1_ from user user0_ left outer join orderd orderds1_ on user0_.id=orderds1_.userid where user0_.id=1 and orderds1_.title=?


    Hibernate: select orderds0_.userid as userid4_0_0_, orderds0_.id as id1_0_0_, orderds0_.id as id1_0_1_, orderds0_.description as descript2_0_1_, orderds0_.title as title3_0_1_ from orderd orderds0_ where orderds0_.userid=?
```

Obviously, the first SQL met my needs, but due to the second SQL, the result was wrong.
I really hope someone can help me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change return statement of your `toPredicate` function inside `Specification<User>` implementation:

```
return criteriaBuilder.and(userIdEqual, orderdTitleEqual);
```

**EDIT**
If I understand correctly, you want to write a specification for `User` who has an `Orderd` with specific `Orderd.title` in `@OneToMany` association represented by `User.orders`, right?

If so, then your specification is pointless, because you basically asking, if `User` with specific `id` has and `Order` with specific `title`. If you want ALL users, you can write following specification:

```
Specification<User> withOrderd(Orderd order) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> builder.isMember(order, root.get("orderds"));
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
Orderd order = ...; //pull order by title from database
List<User> users = userRepository.findAll(withOrderd(order));
```

Otherwise, you can make another `Specification` for ID:

```
Specification<User> withID(int id) {
    return (root, query, builder) ->  builder.equal(root.get("id"), id);
}
```

and use it:

```
Optional<User> user = userRepository.findOne(withOrderd(order).and(withID(id)));
```

Comment: Modified my answer.